# SLD Resolution - Derivation Tree

Tags: prolog

I have the following query, facts and a predicate. Based on these I want to extract the derivation steps.

```
 ?- a(Result). 
 a(1).
 a(X) :- b(X,Y), c(Y).
 b(1, a).   c(b).
 b(2, b).   c(c).
```

I know that I have to go from top to down and from left to right. So for the first fact is X=1.
But then, how can I proceed ? Could someone give me a guideline how to keep on with the extraction of the derivation steps?

Comment: Start with your query: `a(Result).` and look at your facts and rules, starting from the top, as you said. The first fact/rule is `a(1).` which matches `a(Result)` if `Result = 1`. So that is your first successful query result (`Result = 1`). If you tell Prolog you want to find more (entering `;`), then it will backtrack and move on to `a(X) :- b(X,Y), c(Y).` Can you follow it from there?

Comment: @lurker Thanks. So after your instructions, 1 will be assigned to X and after that we will have `b(1,Y),c(Y)` . But, the program will go further down and it will discover `b(1,a)`. That means, that `b(1,Y),c(Y)` will become now `b(1,a),c(a)`. Is my thinking right so far ?

Comment: It will execute `b(X,Y), c(Y).` clause in steps. So after it finds `b(1,a)` with the `b(X,Y)` call, it instantiates `X = 1, Y = a` and moves on to `c(Y)` which now is really `c(a).` However, `c(a)` fails! So it *backtracks* to the `b(X,Y)` again and finds the next success for that, which is `b(2,b)`, which instantiates, `X = 2, Y = b`, then moves on again to `c(Y)` (which is now `c(b)` and that succeeds!`. So then `a(Result)` call succeeds with `Result = 2`. Now if you do this call after entering `trace.` you will see this in gory detail. :)

Comment: @lurker Oh cool. But wait a minute. The last fact/rule `c(c)` is not going to be used ?

Comment: It might be used. After success, Prolog can go back again (if you press `;`) and might try that option, which may or many not succeed.